# PPT to Video Converter for Windows

Tags: windows, gratis, powerpoint

Am looking for a free PPT to Video converter. I searched google and found 4 softwares:

1. Leawo PPT to Video Converter 2.6
2. Mov Avi PPT to Video Converter
3. Moyea PPT to Video Converter 2.7.4
4. RZ Powerpoint Converter

The problem is that all these softwares put a watermark in the converted video. This was the only problem.

So suggest me a software which converts PPT to video formats, even if it is a trial, but watermark should not come in the video.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to Power Point 2010 or later you can:

1. Create your presentation.
2. (Optional) Record and add narration and timings to a slide show and Turn your mouse into a laser pointer.
3. Save the presentation.
4. On the File menu, click Save & Send.
5. Under Save & Send, click Create a video.
6. To display all video quality and size options, under Create a video, click the Computer & HD Displays down arrow.
7. Do one of the following:

   - To create a video with very high quality, yet a large file size, click Computer & HD Displays.
   - To create a video with a moderate file size and medium quality, click Internet & DVD.
   - To create a video with the smallest file size, yet low quality, click Portable Devices.
8. Click the Don't Use Recorded Timings and Narrations down arrow and then, do one of the following:

   - If you did not record and time voice narration and laser pointer movements , click Don't Use Recorded Timings and Narration.
   - If you recorded and timed narration and pointer movements , click Use Recorded Timings and Narrations.
9. Click Create Video.
10. In the File name box, enter a file name for the video, browse for folder that will contain this file, and then click Save. You can track the progress of the video creation by looking at the status bar at the bottom of your screen. The video creation process can take up to several hours depending on the length of the video and the complexity of the presentation.

*Information from the Microsoft Web Site*

**Or of course you could simply run a screen capture program while clicking through your presentation in full screen mode.**

Comment: Thats great, but audio is not coming. What to do to get the audio too ?

Comment: @TominJacob - If you are using the screen capture option take a look at http://camstudio.org/ if you are using the Power Point Option then take a look at the settings you are using.

Comment: Please tell in detail